Looking for graphical JSON editor
I'm looking for a software that can load a JSON file and show it like a spreadsheet with the option to search and filter the data. Editing and saving are optional, but would be great as well.
Easiest would be to just use LibreOffice Calc, but it can't import (let export) JSON.
Does anyone know a stand-alone tool for this use case or a way to get JSON into (and out of) Calc without complicated extra steps?

My best find so far is https://jsoneditoronline.org, but I'd prefer a software that I can run locally without the need to be connected to the internet or to upload data to some online platform.

did you explore any of [these suggestions]https://www.linuxlinks.com/best-free-open-source-json-tools/)?

https://github.com/jspreadsheet/ce
